# webサーバー　tomcat8 jdbc

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc

VPSを借りてJavaでWebアプリケーションをデプロイしようとしています。
現在、サーバー内でJavaのプログラムを以下の接続情報で実行するとMySQLに接続することができ、select文が実行できました。

```
 String driver   = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
 String server   = "localhost";
 String dbname   = "データベース名";
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + dbname ;
```

しかし、同じ条件でTomcatから(WEBアプリケーションから)接続しようとすると、接続できません。(DBからデータをとってくるところでエラーが起きているっぽい。DB接続が必要ない画面は正常に表示される)

TOMCAT_HOME/libにjdbcのwarファイルを入れています。
環境変数には、以下を追加しています

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar
```

また、Tomcatを再起動した際、以下のように表示されます。

```
Starting tomcat: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

最後のusing Classpathに、jdbcが表示される必要があるのかと考えたのですが、表示される必要があるのかないのか、他に原因があるのか、何をすれば接続できるのかわかりません。
どなたかわかる方がいたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします